# Errors with set_add and set_contains

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have currently made a set ADT which uses linked list functions to implement the given interface.

The testing utility we have for testing the set ADT gives me errors on set_add and set_contains.

```
// Push function, pushes element on head of set
void Push(set_t **set, void *elem) {
        // Allocates memory for a newNode
        set_t *newNode = (set_t *) malloc(sizeof(set_t));
        // sets element to elem which is in input
        newNode->elem = elem;
        // Previous head to next
        newNode->next = *set;
        // Newnode as head
        *set = newNode;
}

void AppendNode(set_t **headRef, void *elem) {
        set_t *current = *headRef;
        set_t *newNode;

        newNode = malloc(sizeof(set_t));
        newNode->elem = elem;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        if (current == NULL) {
                *headRef = newNode;
        }
        else {
                while ( current->next != NULL) {
                        current = current->next;
                }
                current->next = newNode;
        }
}

/*
 * Adds the given element to the given set.
 */
void set_add(set_t *set, void *elem) {
        if (set_contains(set, elem) == 1) {
                return;
        }
        else {
                AppendNode(&set, elem);
        }
}

/*
 * Returns 1 if the given element is contained in
 * the given set, 0 otherwise.
 */
int set_contains(set_t *set, void *elem) {
        set_t *current = set;

        while (current != NULL) {
                if (current->elem == elem) {
                        return 1;
                }
                current = current->next;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

It doesn't matter if I use Push to push on head or use AppendNode to add on the tail end.

Here's my set struct:

```
struct set { 
   void *elem; 
   set_t *next; 
   cmpfunc_t cmpfunc; 
}
```

Does someone see something that is very off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Push` and `AppendNode` functions look okay. The error is with `set_add`, where you update the `set` local to `set_add`. This change will not be reflected in the function that calls `set_add`.

You should change the function to:

```
void set_add(set_t **set, void *elem) {
    if (set_contains(*set, elem) == 0) {
        AppendNode(set, elem);
    }
}
```

The function `set_contains` doesn't require the pointer-to-pointer parameter, because it only inspects the set, but doesn't change it.

**Edit** The question requires the given function prototypes to be used. In that case, you should make `set_t` an interface to the linked list that contains the head node. All functions receive this interface as a pointer.

An example implementation might look like this:

The interface, defined in, say, `set.h`, which declares `set_t` as an opaque type:

```
typedef struct set set_t;

set_t *set_create(void);
void set_destroy(set_t *set);
void set_add(set_t *set, void *elem);
int set_contains(const set_t *set, void *elem);
```

The implementation in `set.c` defines the contents of the struct. It also defines a type for the nodes, which is private to `set.c`. And, of course, it implements the functions:

```
#include <set.h>

typedef struct setnode setnode_t;

struct set {
    setnode_t *head;
};

struct setnode { 
   void *elem; 
   setnode_t *next; 
};

set_t *set_create(void)
{
    set_t *set = malloc(sizeof(*set));

    if (set) set->head = NULL;
    return set;
}

void set_destroy(set_t *set)
{
    setnode_t *curr = set->head;

    while (curr) {
        setnode_t *next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
        curr = next;
    }

    free(set);
}

int set_contains(const set_t *set, void *elem)
{
    setnode_t *curr = set->head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        if (curr->elem == elem) return 1;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

void set_add(set_t *set, void *elem)
{
    if (set_contains(set, elem) == 0) {
        setnode_t *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

        node->elem = elem;
        node->next = set->head;
        set->head = node;
    }
}
```

Client code can then use the set like so:

```
#include <set.h>

int main()
{
    set_t *set = set_create();

    for (size_t i = 3; i < 17; i++, i++) {
        set_add(set, (void *) i);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%4zu %d\n", i, set_contains(set, (void *) i));
    }

    set_destroy(set);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The set_add and set_contains are given from the set.h which I cannot change to therefore I can't use reference pointers as arguments in them. 

But after posting this I looked at an example we have where the cmpfunc was used on set_contains. if(current->cmpfunc(elem, current->elem == 0) { return 1; }

Cmpfunc is defined as this "typedef int (*cmpfunc_t)(void *, void *);.

Comment: Okay, so your interface is given and you have to provide an implementation, right? In that case, you could rename your `set_t` to `setnode_t` and make it private to the implementation. Your `set_t` could then be a structrue containing the head node; `typedef struct { setnode_t *head; } set_t;` The struct is passed to the functions via pointer, so that updates to the head are reflected. (And the interface to `set_contains` should be made a `const set_t*`.)

Comment: Of course, a linked list is not a very efficient implementation of a set. But you can use the interface-struct approach for binary trees and other data structures. In fact, it allows you to mask the implementation from the user.

Comment: I am still a beginner, but let me try to think aloud - this struct with the headnode - should it be used in all the other functions, like in the set_create etc? How would you use it - with the structure of the implementation I already have?

Comment: And yes - I know it isn't efficient, I am just hacking it together at the last minute...

Comment: It's probably best to answer you with an addition to the answer. Is the full `struct` definition part of the given interface. ("Full" as opposed to just `typedef struct set set_t` without the fields in curly braces.)

Comment: No - it's just a typedef and an empty struct skeleton. 

struct set;
typedef struct set set_t;

Comment: I might have fixed the problem I had earlier, now it is having problem with insertion and copying and I think it's the copying that's the problem. 

set_t *set_copy(set_t *set) {
set_T *copy = NULL; copy = set_intersection(set, copy); return copy;
}

In theory this should work because intersection returns a set of both sets added together.

Comment: Hmmm. With your current structure and interface, you'll always have problems when updating or creating a new set. I've extended my answer to show how an approach with an intermediate structure might look like.

Comment: Thanks! I am grateful for helpful people! This might afterall save my exam ^.^ (the second one this week, that's why I had little time to implement a balanced tree)